# Spark SQL - generic Dataset reader

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to create generic DataSet[T] reader in order to avoid dataframe.as[..] for each reader call.
There's support for primitive types and case classes so I was thinking about something like:

```
def read[T <: Product](sql : String): Dataset[T] = {
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.option("query", sql).load()
  df.as[T]
}
```

But I'm getting 'Unable to find encoder for type stored in Dataset' error.
Is it possible to do something like that ?

Second cycle:

```
def read[T <: Product](sql : String) : Dataset[T] = {
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  innerRead(sql)
}

private def innerRead[T <: Product : Encoder](sql : String): Dataset[T] = {
  val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.option("query", sql).load()
  df.as[T]
}
```

ends with type mismatch (foudn Encoder[Nothing] , required Encoder[T]).

I was trying to import newProductEncoder only , but ended the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to convert a `DataFrame` to a `Dataset` you need to have an `Encoder`. You can do it by simply adding a context bound on and `Encoder` for `T`:

```
def read[T <: Product : Encoder](sql : String): Dataset[T] = {
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.option("query", sql).load()
  df.as[T]
}
```

A context bound is syntactic sugar for the following:

```
def read[T <: Product](sql : String)(implicit $ev: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T]
```

which means that you need to have in the implicit context one (and only one) instance of an `Encoder[T]`.

This is needed because the `as` method itself requires this context bound.

Spark itself can provide you most of the `Encoder`s you may need (primitives, `String`s and `case class`es so far) by importing (as you did) the implicits for your `SparkSession`. These, however, must be available in the implicit scope at call site, meaning that what you want to have is probably more like the following:

```
def read[T <: Product : Encoder](spark: SparkSession, sql: String): Dataset[T] = {
  import spark.implicits._
  val df: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.read.option("query", sql).load()
  df.as[T]
}

val spark: SparkSession = ??? // your SparkSession object
import spark.implicits._
val ds: Dataset[YourType] = read[YourType](spark, "select something from a_table")
```

Comment: thanks, i extended the original question with new details.

Comment: `read` doesn't specify the context bound, which means that `innerRead` it cannot see it. The context bound _must_ be propagated throughout your calls. However, in order for the implicits to be available at the right moment, you have to import them at call site rather that as you define you method.

Answer (score 1):

In your second cycle, perhaps you need to give the type parameter to your innerRead call:

```
innerRead[T](sql)
```